# Как ведет себя .htaccess конструкция?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, denwer

Как поведет себя данная `.htaccess конструкция`:

```
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .exe
```

Будет ли она запускать EXE-файлы на сервере и выдавать результат пользователю в браузер? 
Обязательно ли устанавливать для этого Denwer, или Apache вполне сойдет?

Спасибо.

Comment: Я тоже когда-то интересовался этим и даже вопрос на форуме задавал, но до конца так и не понял...

Answer (score 1):

Взяли бы и попробовали, стало бы ясно...

А вообще AddHandler определяет какой обработчик использовать для данных типов файлов. Оно должно запускать exe файлы, но как cgi скрипты.

А denwer и есть apache, только там в пакете сразу идет еще php,mysql.

Comment: А запуск exe файлов каким образом происходить будет на Windows сервере? В браузере пользователя покажется?

Comment: @WILD_BEAST, [Википедия: CGI][1]. CGI - программа, работающая со стандартным вводом/выводом.
Эквивалентно консольной программе, только вывод идет не в консоль, а через http в браузер.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI